# How to type only random letters in input field with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

Pls say, How I can past only letters in my tests.
Like this

```
    const uuid = () => Cypress._.random('^[A-Za-z]+$')
    const id = uuid()
    const firstname = `${id}`

    cy.get('.firstname').type(firstname)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: Or you could just use some library for generating random/fake data. For example https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/

Comment: I see that answer, But Can I write with regexp, don't write all the letters? ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score 0):

⚠ If you want to generate UUIDs be aware that not all characters in a UUID are random: Read here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

---

### [UUID](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid)

I personally use this small package to generate UUIDs

---

### [Chance.js](https://chancejs.com/miscellaneous/guid.html)

If you need more generated data for your tests I'd recommend chance.js. You can read more about generating UUIDs here [chance.js/uuid](https://chancejs.com/miscellaneous/guid.html)

---

### On your own

Generating UUIDs on your own was already answered in this mega thread here: [How to create GUID / UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-guid-uuid)

If you don't care if some of the strings are duplicates of each other (e.g. for first names), you could just

```js
const generate = () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `${document.body.innerHTML} ${Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="generate()">
    Generate string
  </button>
</body>

</html>
```